# Good audio mixer for Jack Audio Connection Kit

Tags: 14.04, jack

Does anyone know of a good audio mixer for JACK?
I just need it to monitor my sound, maybe change bass, treble, or maybe use a equalizer.

I am looking for something similar to Voicemeeter.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: JACK itself doesn't do mixing. You would need to control the volume either in the software side that is sending data to jack, or on the hardware side, either directly via hardware mixing, or with alsamixer on your sound card for example. There are many metering tools available in the archives that can be connected to jack's outputs.

Comment: I know that JACK cannot directly do mixing, but I just need it for adjusting volumes, effects and stuff. Something similar to Voicemeeter.... and I dont own a hardware mixer...

Comment: Maybe it would be better if you described what you're trying to do exactly then. If you're doing audio production work, the DAW you're using should have a mixer built in.  If you're just piping random sounds through jack, then you need to insert a mixer application for jack in between the sound generators and the jack outputs, such as `jack-mixer` which is in the archive.